# how to remove leading plus (+) signs from code block in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sed, eclipse-plugin

I have cut&pasted a large code block into Eclipse from a patch. Thus, it has lines starting with '+' which I want to remove. How do I do that? Bonus: Is there a way to pipe selected blocks through sed?

Comment: Why didn't you apply the patch instead?

Comment: Well, it had a complicated merge conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e 's/^[+]//' YourFile
```

this remove any first character `+` from any line. I assume you are under linux with GNU sed where `-i` is available.
note: the square bracket around `+` are not mandatory with `-e` under GNU sed

Answer (score 0):

sed default uses BRE, so you just type `+`, it has no special meaning:

```
kent$  echo '+foo'|sed 's/^+//'
foo
```